# New to scikit.learn and kmeans, How to clusterize documents (From File) using K means?

Tags: python, parsing, machine-learning, k-means, scikit-learn

What i am trying to do is using Kmeans from scikit.learn to Clusterize pure text documents into Two Categories.

Here is use-case scenario. 
I will recieve a few sample sets which are going to be tagged as "Important" and which are Going to be tagged as "Un-Important".

From scikit.learn examples data set is predefined format from newsgroups :

```
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', categories=categories,
                             shuffle=True, random_state=42)
```

What i want to do is to receive data from Text files (20newsgroups seems not text file at all , i cannot even unzip it)

What i am not clear is the data structure of that fetch_20newsgroups and how it works.
And what should i do to convert Text Files into required format (Such one provided by  fetch_20newsgroups)

Thanks

Phyo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 20 newsgroups dataset loader shipped with scikit-learn fetches the archive of text documents downloaded from the original site at http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/20newsgroups/20newsgroups.html and then cache them in a compressed format in the `$HOME/scikit_learn_data` folder. Have a look at the [source code of the 20 newsgroups dataset loader](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.py) for more details.

To load your own set of text files as a scikit-learn "bunch" object you can use the [sklearn.datasets.load_files](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_files.html) function directly by pointing it to the right folder.

If your data is already categorized into 2 categories (e.g. two subfolders named "Important" and "Un-Important") then what you need to use is not a clustering algorithm which is unsupervised but a classification such as MultinomialNB (Naive Bayes), LinearSVC (Linear Support Vector Machine) or LogisticRegression which are supervised as in the [text classification example](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html).

If you don't know which document belongs to which category but want to group your corpus into 2 groups of similar documents then you can use unsupervised clustering algorithms such as KMeans but it's very unlikely that the 2 clusters you will get match your idea "Important" and "Un-important".

Comment: Thank you very much , i may have more question for NB and LinearSVC after testing .load_files method. I will invite you there.

Comment: hey @ogrisel , can you answer my question here?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13068257/200044 i am planning to implement multiprocessing on scikit-learn